# Error while running server in Wagtail CMS

Tags: python, django, wagtail

This error happens when I add a banner title. Banner title I believe is the property in the class and it's being referenced as a string. Completely new to DJANGO & Wagtail CMS + only been coding/programming for the last eight months! Any help greatly appreciated (:

Here is what my terminal says

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/.local/share/virtualenvs/wagsite-cck0l_Kh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/.local/share/virtualenvs/wagsite-cck0l_Kh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/.local/share/virtualenvs/wagsite-cck0l_Kh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/.local/share/virtualenvs/wagsite-cck0l_Kh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/.local/share/virtualenvs/wagsite-cck0l_Kh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/.local/share/virtualenvs/wagsite-cck0l_Kh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/.local/share/virtualenvs/wagsite-cck0l_Kh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/.local/share/virtualenvs/wagsite-cck0l_Kh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/Work/Projects/first_wag/wagsite/home/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class HomePage(Page):
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/Work/Projects/first_wag/wagsite/home/models.py", line 12, in HomePage
    banner_title = models.Charfield(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Charfield'
^C%
❯ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/Work/Projects/first_wag/wagsite/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/.local/share/virtualenvs/wagsite-cck0l_Kh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/.local/share/virtualenvs/wagsite-cck0l_Kh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/.local/share/virtualenvs/wagsite-cck0l_Kh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/.local/share/virtualenvs/wagsite-cck0l_Kh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/.local/share/virtualenvs/wagsite-cck0l_Kh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/Work/Projects/first_wag/wagsite/home/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class HomePage(Page):
  File "/Users/alessiolivolsi/Work/Projects/first_wag/wagsite/home/models.py", line 12, in HomePage
    banner_title = models.Charfield(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
```

**Manage.py**

```
from django.db import models

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel



class HomePage(Page):
    ###Home page model###
    templates = "home/home_page.html"

    banner_title = models.Charfield(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("banner_title")
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Charfield` needs a capital F - `CharField`.

Comment: Thank you so much, can't believe it was that simple!